# Are Voldemort and Harry related?

Tags: harry-potter

So if Harry is descended from Ignotus and Voltemort from Peverrels, does that make them long lost cousins?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, [they are related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Voldemort#Family_tree).
[image: in case if something happens with link, there is family tree]

(Tom Marvolo Riddle is Voldemort as you remember :) )

Comment: thank  you for commenting, and not marking as duplicate ;) :)

Answer (score 1):

While they are "related" throgh Peverell brothers, as per @nicael's answer, they aren't "related" any closer:

> Question: Is Voldemort some sort of relative of Harry's? Possibly his mother's brother?
>   **J.K. Rowling responds:** I'm laughing...that would be a bit Star Wars, wouldn't it?
>   (*source: "About the Books: transcript of J.K. Rowling's live interview on Scholastic.com," Scholastic.com, 16 October 2000*)